# Bypass read only cells in DataGridView when pressing TAB key

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can anyone show me some code of how I could bypass read only cells in DatagridView when pressing TAB key?

Comment: take a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71000393/3892975
it is the perfect solution for this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution. I also added a step to set Selected = False on the cell before the SendKeys to get rid of the visual artifact on the last selected cell in the grid before the grid is tabbed out of.  
  
One place I know of where there is a minor issue is if you have AllowUserToDeleteRows = True . The workaround is to set the SelectionMode = FullRowSelect , not perfect visually but pretty good.  
  
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Overriding the SelectionChanged event is the right approach.  The property CurrentCell can be used to set the current cell. You want something like this:

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell currentCell = dataGridView.CurrentCell;
    if (currentCell != null)
    {
        int nextRow = currentCell.RowIndex;
        int nextCol = currentCell.ColumnIndex + 1;
        if (nextCol == dataGridView.ColumnCount)
        {
            nextCol = 0;
            nextRow++;
        }
        if (nextRow == dataGridView.RowCount)
        {
            nextRow = 0;
        }
        DataGridViewCell nextCell = dataGridView.Rows[nextRow].Cells[nextCol];
        if (nextCell != null && nextCell.Visible)
        {
            dataGridView.CurrentCell = nextCell;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to add a test for the current cell being read only and loop while the next cell is invisible or read only. You'll also need to check to make sure that you don't loop for ever if all cells are read only.

You'll have to cope with the case where the display index is different to the base index too.

To get this behaviour just when pressing Tab you'll need to add a KeyDown handler:

```
private void AlbumChecker_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        SelectNextEditableCell(DataGridView dataGridView);
    }
}
```

and put the first code in this new method.

You might want to check that the DataGridView has focus too.

Comment: but I want this behavior just when pressing the 'TAB' key not when using the mouse too

Comment: @Cornel - don't know what to suggest really. What behaviour do you see? Do some more reading on the DataGridView methods in the MSDN documentation. It might take a bit of digging, but usually the information is there.

Comment: This is a convoluted way of achieving the goal and it doesn't work in all cases. DatagridView.ColumnCount gives the number of columns for the grid view including invisible columns. If there are any invisible columns in the grid view, this method will fail. That can be addressed by adding some more code and making the method even more convoluted.

@Neer's solution further down is much more accurate and elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I did an example inheriting `DataGridView` class. The example works for TAB and ENTER keys so the user can quickly insert data, but can still use the mouse or the up, down, right, left keys to select the cells and copy them to an excel. It works simulating several TABs until the Grid gets to a non ReadOnly Cell. Hope it’s useful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
  class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
  {
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
      if (keyData == Keys.Enter || keyData == Keys.Tab)
      {
        MyProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab);
        return true;
      }
      return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
      {
        MyProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab);
        return true;
      }
      return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }

    protected bool MyProcessTabKey(Keys keyData)
    {
      bool retValue = base.ProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab);
      while (this.CurrentCell.ReadOnly)
      {
        retValue = base.ProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab);
      }
      return retValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit DataGridView and override ProcessDialogKey (for key pressed while editing) and ProcessDataGridViewKey (for key pressed while not editing). When Tab was pressed, set CurrentCell to the next non-readonly cell.

Optionally override WndProc to filter mouse clicks on readonly cells. (See DataGridView.GetColumnDisplayRectangle to find which column was clicked).

Good source to start from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2025a294-9143-4ecf-82b1-f632da163e85).

Answer (score 0):

When the cell is in edit mode, and you want to listen to keystroke events, you might try handling the DataGridView's EditingControlShowing event...

```
Private Sub myDvGrid_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles myDvGrid.EditingControlShowing
    Dim c As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = DirectCast(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)

    RemoveHandler c.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf edtctrlOn_PreviewKeyDown
    RemoveHandler c.TextChanged, AddressOf edtctrlOn_TextChanged

    AddHandler c.TextChanged, AddressOf edtctrlOn_TextChanged
    AddHandler c.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf edtctrlOn_PreviewKeyDown

End Sub
```

Then, in the edtctrlOn_PreviewKeyDown event, you can bubble the arguments over to the original datagrid's PreviewKeyDown event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Hector - 
I hope you are still listening.  Your solution is the most elegant and straightforward one I've seen in extensive searching.  I've run into the suggestion to override the key events, but your suggestion to invoke base.ProcessTabKey is especially simple and it handles focus passing to the next control when you reach the end of the dgv.  The one additional thing your solution needed was a check in MyProcessTabKey for the last cell of the dgv.  If that cell is readonly and the user tabs in the previous cell, the while statement goes into an infinite loop.  Adding the following code as the first statement in the while loop seems to solve the problem, though it does leave the last (readonly) cell the "active" cell (meaning it appears as though it's selected).

```
    if (this.CurrentCell.RowIndex == this.Rows.Count - 1
                && this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == this.Columns.Count - 1)
                { retValue = false; break; }
```

I have a follow-on question.  Do you or anyone else know how to make this approach work with Shift-Tab, so the dgv skips readonly cells in a backward direction as well?  Since Shift and Tab are different key events, I don't know how to detect Shift-Tab in the overridden ProcessDialogKey and ProcessDataGridViewKey methods.
Thanks.  Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can catch Tab Key by this code in ProcessDialogKey

```
    Dim uKeyCode As Keys = (keyData And Keys.KeyCode)
    Dim uModifiers As Keys = (keyData And Keys.Modifiers)

    (uKeyCode = Keys.Return OrElse uKeyCode = Keys.Tab) AndAlso uModifiers = Keys.Shift
```

And by this code in ProcessDataGridViewKey

```
    (e.KeyCode = Keys.Return OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab) AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (e.KeyValue == 13)
        {
            e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Tab);
        }
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.